# Assign an ImageIcon to a JList

Tags: java

If I have a `JList` with 3 items (orange, apple, banana) and I want to display an image for each item using a `JLabel`, how can I do that?

```
private void jList2ValueChanged(javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent evt) {                                    
    // TODO adds your handling code here:
    try {
        if (evt.getSource() == "orange") {
            ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("pic/rea.png" + jList2.getSelectedValue());
            jLabel2.setIcon(icon);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        //do nothing
    }
}
```

Comment: i'm doing this as part of a bigger project .. i've 500+ code but the only bit i'm stuck at is assigning the value of a list to a picture where i searched for days to try to solve it but instead of posting the actual code i made this one to serve the same purpose without making the post too long !

Comment: So what have you tried?  Are you getting an error?  Is the result not as you're expected?  Have you tried [debugging](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)?  Frankly, this looks like a "write my code for me" question, and Stack Overflow is not a programmers-for-free service.

Comment: debugging won't work i tried that .. i know what was wrong with the code i used the same variable twice in actionlistener which cause it to show none of the values .

Comment: Well, if debugging doesn't work, then I'm afraid nobody on this planet is capable of solving your problem.  Because that is how the most difficult of programming problems are solved.

Comment: `"pic/rea.png" + jList2.getSelectedValue()` - that looks fishy. Let's say that method call returns `329`, then your picture file path will be `pic/rea.png329`. Maybe you wanted to do `"pic/rea" + jList2.getSelectedValue() + ".png"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the CellRenderer of your List. Example:

```
private void initGUI() {
    Image orange = getOrangeImage();
    Image apple = getAppleImage();
    // ...

    Map<String, Icon> icons = new HashMap<>();
    icons.put("orange", new ImageIcon(orange));
    icons.put("apple", new ImageIcon(apple));
    // ...

    JList<String> list = new JList<>(new String[] { "orange", "apple", "banana" });
    list.setCellRenderer(new FruitRenderer(icons));
    // ...
}

class FruitRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer {

    private final Map<String, Icon> icons;

    FruitRenderer(Map<String, Icon> icons) {
        this.icons = Objects.requireNonNull(icons);
    }

    @Override
    public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index,
            boolean isSelected, boolean cellHasFocus) {

        Component comp = super.getListCellRendererComponent(list, value, index, isSelected, cellHasFocus);
        if (value instanceof String) {
            Icon icon = icons.get(value);
            ((JLabel) comp).setIcon(icon);
        }
        return comp;
    }
}
```

Note: DefaultCellListener extends JLabel and is used to render each list cell.

Note2: obviously you must not pass the map of icons to the Renderer, it's just an example.